# Can I claim home-improvement expenses on a rental I live in but do not own?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, rental-property

My father owns a house that he rents to me. I take care of all the maintenance and upkeep like lawn care, and repairs. He doesn't claim any of these on his taxes. Can I claim these expenses on my taxes? The house is my primary residence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim it how? If I rent, I don't get to deduct rent on my Federal taxes, although some states offer a small deduction. If I own, my own house maintenance is just a cost like my other bills, not a deduction.

The real issue is whether your father is handling the rest of this transaction properly. If he is your landlord, these are his costs and he should pay for them and take them off his taxes via schedule E.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just wanted to make sure I was doing my taxes right. Thank you again!